# Match trailing spaces but not lines of spaces using JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, removing-whitespace

I want to match trailing spaces at the end of lines, but not if the line is entirely made of whitespace.

These whitespaces should then be replaced.

The following expression uses negative lookahead to match these whitespace lines, but does not seem to work.

```
/(?!^( |&nbsp;)+$)( |&nbsp;)+$/gm
```

Here is a sample input

```
#The following line's trailing spaces should match
Foo  &nbsp;  

#But not a line full of whitespace
  &nbsp;
```

And here a snippet

```js
var oRegExp = /(?!^( |&nbsp;)+$)( |&nbsp;)+$/;

// Test cases
var test = function (sInput, sOutput) {
    var oMatch = sInput.match(oRegExp);
    var bSuccess = (oMatch === null && sOutput === null) || oMatch[0] === sOutput;
    console.log('"' + sInput + '" ', bSuccess ? 'success' : 'failed');
};
test('Foo  &nbsp;  ', '  &nbsp;  ');
test('  &nbsp;  ', null);
test('', null);
```

[Regex101 sample](https://regex101.com/r/wf0spU/1)

Answer (score 2):

Use regex as [`/\S\s+$/`](https://regex101.com/r/3H4E43/1) which matches any non-whitespace character followed by whitespace at the end. Or more specific regex [`/[^ ][ ]+$/`](https://regex101.com/r/yhxjD7/2) which doesn't include newline char, tab space, etc.

Few more suggestions:

1. Actually, you are giving the argument as a regex so `RegExp` is completely unnecessary here.
2. The global flag doesn't have any role in your code since it only occurs once.
3. Use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method for getting a boolean value when the string is matched.

```js
var oRegExp = /\S\s+$/;
// or more specific
// oRegExp = /[^ ][ ]+$/;

var sValidInput = 'Foo    ';
var sInvalidInput = '    ';

console.log('"' + sValidInput + '" should match: ', oRegExp.test(sValidInput));
console.log('"' + sInvalidInput + '" should not match: ', oRegExp.test(sInvalidInput));
```

---

**UPDATE :** Use regex [`/^(?!(?: |&nbsp;)+$).*?( |&nbsp;)+$/`](https://regex101.com/r/IdIuvz/3) which used [negative look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match any other combination.

```js
var oRegExp = /^(?!(?: |&nbsp;)+$).*?( |&nbsp;)+$/;

var sValidInput = 'Foo  &nbsp;  ';
var sInvalidInput = '  &nbsp;  ';


console.log('"' + sValidInput + '" should match: ', oRegExp.test(sValidInput));
console.log('"' + sInvalidInput + '" should not match: ', oRegExp.test(sInvalidInput));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Actually, my usecase is a bit more complex, and I guess the \s won't do, I'll edit the question

Comment: See my edited question, as for why I was going for the negative lookahead option. Any idea of why it doesn't work the way I imagined?

Comment: Thanks for the update. As stated in the question (and more explicitly so now), I would like to match these whitespaces, and have updated the test case.

Comment: Well, I want to match whitespace, not the line containing whitespace. In the end, this whitespace is going to be replaced by another char sequence.